# Find use of HTML tags and attributes in SQL database

Tags: html, sql, postgresql, grep, xss

I am writing some anti-XSS code and would like to whitelist common HTML tags and their corresponding attributes.

I have a large database of customer entered HTML in a PostgresSQL database and would like to mine the data to figure out which tags are commonly used in different columns.

I'm thinking of dumping the database to plain text and using grep or a shell script to find the common tags. What is a good way to do this? I'm open to anything that will work in UNIX (OSX) or in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Use a proper HTML parser. If you have PL/Perl or PL/Python available then you might (or not, I haven't tried this myself) be able to do the mangling without leaving the database.

Comment: +1 @muistooshort: pl/php, pl/ruby, and others are other options too, depending on what you're most comfortably with. But definitely a pl function (possibly as a before insert/update trigger).

Comment: Please read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html then get a proper HTML parser, you'll save a lot of time. PL/Python's BeautifulSoup works well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at OWASP java HTML Serializer, OWASP AntiSamy or Jsoup

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project
http://jsoup.org/